# Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel

I Have this Code

```
    $tempid = DB::table('local_founders')->select('entry_by')->where('founder_id', $id)->get();

    if($tempid[0] != Auth::user()->id){
      return Redirect::to('founder')->with('messagetext','Record Not Found !')->with('msgstatus','error');
     }
```

but Results in this Error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Comment: what is $id?? can you show `dd($id)`??

Comment: can you show dd($tempid)

Comment: @Davit its integer the result is "269"

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Result is Array array:1 [▼
  0 => {#900 ▼
    +"entry_by": 10
  }
]

Comment: Update this on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tempid = DB::table('local_founders')->select('entry_by')->where('founder_id', $id)->get();
```

returns a collection, if you need the first element, change to this:

```
$temp = DB::table('local_founders')->select('entry_by')->where('founder_id', $id)->first()
```

now *$temp* is an stdClass, after that you can access it easily like any other stdClass object as follows: `$temp->entry_by`

so I think you have to change your code as follow:

```
   $local_founder = DB::table('local_founders')->select('entry_by')->where('founder_id', $id)->first();
    if($local_found->entry_by != Auth::user()->id){return Redirect::to('founder')->with('messagetext','Record Not Found !')->with('msgstatus','error');}
```

Comment: Output of dd($local_founder->entry_by);?

Comment: [▼ 0 => {#900 ▼ +"entry_by": 10 } ]

Comment: strange, it's an array! are you sure you exectured `dd($local_founder->entry_by)` not `dd($local_founder)`??

Comment: Thanks Ahmed,ITs Ok now ,I ran old code ,it works now